# Why doesn't my program recognize the input "q" and break the loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm writing a main method that asks the user for input in the form of the length of the radius and height of a cone, and then calls 3 other mathematical methods to determine the area of the bottom of the cone, as well as the surface area and volume of it.

The idea is that you should be able to enter several sets of inputs, and signal that you're done by entering "q". An example input could for example be " 10 5 6 8 q". The program should then calculate everything two times, with two sets of radius and height and then break the loop. Instead,  it does the calculations 3 times, where the last two are identical. Also it doesn't jump to the next piece of code after the infinite loop.

```
outerLoop: while(true)       //Infinite loop
{   
if (scan.hasNextInt())       //If next input is an integer, read it
{
radie = scan.nextInt();
height = scan.nextInt();
}
else if (scan.next().equals('q'))
{                          //If it instead if "q", break the loop  
    break outerLoop;
}
     System.out.print("r = "+radius);
     System.out.println("h = "+height);
     System.out.println("Bottom area:      "+ area(radius));
     System.out.println("Surface area:   "+area(radie, height));
     System.out.println("Volume:              "+ volume(radius, height));

}

}
```

Comment: when you call `scan.next()` the scanner reads the next token.  if it isn't `'q'` then it is a number but you didn't store it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a String (scan.next()) with a char 'q', which will never be equal.

Comment: How would you go about comparing them then?

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (scan.next().equals("q"))
{                          
    break outerLoop;
}
```

You are comparing a String vs a Char. Try with this and it will work.